# Symbol found on an IFR low chart

Tags: aeronautical-charts, ifr-navigation

I see this symbol on an IFR low chart, can someone tell me what it is?
[image: IFR chart]

Comment: Does the symbol have an associated name depicted? Or if you right-click the area on Skyvector, can you see the name? Look that name up in the FAA's [8260-2 database](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/Radio_Fix_Holding_8260/) and it should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: This symbol appears, e.g. [on enroute charts](https://skyvector.com/?ll=36.489959182066556,-121.447580396821&chart=403&zoom=1). What puzzles me is you were not able to find it [on the chart legend](https://skyvector.com/?ll=32.999841774917215,-117.74776792961238&chart=403&zoom=1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More context would be better. The screenshot you posted indicates that there *is* a navaid information box above and to the left of the symbol, but you cut it off so we cannot see what it says. If we knew the name of the navaid we could search for it in the [8260-2 database](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/Radio_Fix_Holding_8260/) and we would know more about it.

But just the symbol itself is enough to know exactly what it represents (which is the point of there being a symbol at all, of course). As TomMcW pointed out, everything you need to know about the charts can be found in the [Chart User's Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/). However, it is not a Compass Locator Beacon but rather a Non-Directional Beacon. (A compass locator is a specific use case of an NDB.)

We can see the difference in the two symbols when they are side-by-side:

> [image]
> Left: CLB; Right: NDB

A Compass Locator Beacon has two layers of larger and darker brown dots surrounding its central circle, while a normal NDB has four layers of smaller and lighter brown dots. The image you posted clearly depicts an NDB and not a CLB.

You will find CLBs associated with instrument landing systems, as Tom said. NDBs may also be depicted as the outer marker of an ILS, but they can also appear elsewhere, for example on an airport proper.

Comment: On the [US low enroute charts](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/ifr/), [NDB and locator have the same appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnA4I.png). However in the OP there is a North arrow, which seems to indicate a NDB. Why is there a North arrow is another question...

Comment: @mins I'm not sure that's correct. Look at L-27 and compare [ACORE](https://skyvector.com/?ll=38.521018473267155,-90.0582953599821&chart=427&zoom=1) (CP) with [ALGOA](https://skyvector.com/?ll=38.549087982867306,-92.07081570451398&chart=427&zoom=1) (JE). They are different symbols. (Note that both symbols include North arrows, as do on-airport NAVAIDs like [Bloomfield](https://skyvector.com/?ll=40.74503153252627,-92.43052708703816&chart=427&zoom=1) [BEX].)

Comment: You're right, so the legend is wrong?? CP symbol doesn't seem to be part of [the legend](https://skyvector.com/?ll=40.06547055941075,-82.87423648450262&chart=427&zoom=5).

Comment: When an NDB is used as a compass locator as part of an ILS appch it is co-located with the Outer Marker beacon (then it's called a Locator Outer Marker- LOM) or co-located with the Middle Marker beacon (called a Locator Middle Marker- LMM). It is used as a secondary method of identifying when you've passed the OM or MM and as a method of navigating to the approach procedure (sometimes as an IAF and OM) and perhaps starting a procedure turn from that point outbound then turning inbound and being used as the OM. Not common these days. But is a different symbol than shown in the OP's question.

Comment: @757toga: Good information. So we have the NDB, regular large symbol, then the compass locator (low power but same symbol), then the locator collocated with the a marker/LOM/LMM, (smaller symbol). Do you know when North arrows are used?

Comment: @mins I don't. My recollection is that North arrows were not shown when the NDB was used as a LOM/LMM (and on occasion LIM [inner marker].

Comment: Even [more confusion if we add Jeppesen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLmYA.png) to the loop. Only three rings. The best is to accelerate NDB and locators decommissioning!

Comment: @mins, being a low en-route chart the marker function should not be relevant, so I would expect the number of dots, if it varies on a given chart, to indicate the power/range, no? A low power NDB makes little sense outside an approach, so the fewer dots would only be seen as LOM/LMM, but a high power NDB can still be a LOM (e.g. when it is the only navaid in larger area).

Comment: @JanHudec: That seems logical, and would match the [smaller size of the locator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnA4I.png) on FAA charts. Still [this symbol](https://skyvector.com/?ll=38.521018473267155,-90.0582953599821&chart=427&zoom=1) on enroute charts is a mystery.

Comment: The reason I thought it was a compass locator is the north arrow. I've never seen an ndb with an arrow but not a full compass rose.

Comment: @mins I understand that symbol as NDB (there is frequency 350 given for it), which happens to be co-located with a marker beacon, but that is not really relevant for en-route navigation. It might be smaller because of graphical considerations even. I am somewhat surprised they bothered with the ILS at all (it does not have all or even most ILS).

Comment: @JanHudec: After searching a bit on compass locator, I have clarified a locator is just a certain category of NDB (class L, 15NM range, other classes are MH, H, HH), used specifically for collocation with an ILS marker. As a NDB is has an individual frequency and identification morse code associated. There name comes from ADF predecessor: [radio compass](https://timeandnavigation.si.edu/navigating-air/challenges/overcoming-challenges/radio-navigation).

Answer (score -2):

It is a [compass locator beacon](https://www.pilotscafe.com/glossary/compass-locator)<sup>1</sup>. It’s an NDB located at the outer marker of an ILS. Despite the name it has nothing to do with a compass. According to [ARGOTI](https://www.askacfi.com/4715/why-is-it-called-a-%E2%80%9Ccompass-locator%E2%80%9D.htm) it is called that because the name “actually comes from the old radio compasses installed on airplanes.”

<sup>1</sup> From [FAA Aeronautical Chart User’s Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/editions/12Aug2021/cug-complete.pdf) pg. 70.

Comment: Could also be used as a LMM (locator middle marker) vs LOM (locator outer marker).

Comment: Why do you think it’s a locator rather than an NDB?

Comment: It is not a compass locator beacon. Compass locator beacons have a two-layer circle of brown dots around the central circle; OP's icon has a four-layer circle of brown dots, indicating that is an NDB.

Comment: @zachinquarantine Please accept the other answer. I have misidentified the symbol.